# Can I use "that I like" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I want to say that the following quotes are "motivational quotes that I like".

Is it proper to use "that I like" as an adjective to "motivational quotes" ? It seems to be okay as far as I know.

Is there another way to express this idea in more concise manner? I feel that adding "that" seems to make a sentence longer and more verbose.
For example, I could try to express this way: "Here are my favorite motivational quotes"?

Thank you for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**that I like** is a relative clause that identifies the particular quotes that you like. It is not unusual to omit the relative pronoun **that** in spoken English, so it is possible say

> Here are some motivational quotes I like

Personally, I think that it is clearer to include the relative pronoun, especially in written English.

As an alternative, you could say

> Here are **my favourite** motivational quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use "motivational quotes I like".

'That' can be dropped after reporting verbs such as say (that), tell someone (that), regret (that), imply (that), etc.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.